# Python assert string with variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, assert

If I do the following in python

```
i = 0
assert i == 1, f"expected 1, got {i}"
```

The assert message is

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> ...
> assert i == 1, f"expected 1, got {i}"

How do I get it to show `expected 1, got 0`? It doesn't seem to expand the dynamic string first but treat it as a literal.

Comment: Can you paste the entire traceback? I think that's just showing us the line of code that raised the exception, not the actual error message.

Comment: It works fine on my end. Can you show us your full traceback?

Comment: The problem is probably at your console scroll, output buffer, failure to notice the error message, or something. The `AssertionError: expected 1, got 0` is displayed **after** the traceback. You can hide the traceback (as in the answer below), but I don't see what's that useful for.

Answer (score 5):

If you want *just* the single line printed, without the whole traceback, here's one way to handle it:

```py
import sys

i = 0

try:
    assert i == 1, f"expected 1, got {i}"
except AssertionError as e:
    print(e)
    # print(e, file=sys.stderr) # to print to stderr
    sys.exit(1) # exit program with error
```

You could also intercept the system excepthook or something similar and alter how the traceback is printed out.

Here is working with an excepthook:

```py
import sys

def assertion_excepthook(type, value, traceback):
    if type is AssertionError:
        print(value)
        # with line number:
        print(f"{traceback.tb_lineno}: {value}")
    else:
        sys.__excepthook__(type, value, traceback)

sys.excepthook = assertion_excepthook

i = 0
assert i == 1, f"expected 1, got {i}"
```

This solution is a little more overhead but it means you won't have to do several `try/except` blocks.

Comment: Probably best to print to stderr

Comment: @costaparas good point, I'll add that in!